# subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['mongod', '--bind_ip_all']' died with <Signals.SIGABRT: 6> while running offical monogodb docker image

Tags: linux, mongodb, docker, ubuntu-20.04

I went through https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-community-with-docker/

On [Kubuntu 20.04 Linux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kubuntu) I am trying latest mongodb using `Docker version 20.10.5, build 55c4c88`. I tried running

```bash
sudo docker run --name some-mongo mongodb/mongodb-community-server:6.0.5-ubuntu2204
```

Its giving me error

```bash
alok@alok-HP-Laptop-14s-cf3xxx:/tmp$ sudo docker run --name some-mongo mongodb/mongodb-community-server:6.0.5-ubuntu2204
Warning: File MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME_FILE is deprecated. Use MONGODB_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME_FILE instead.
Warning: File MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD_FILE is deprecated. Use MONGODB_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD_FILE instead.
{"t":{"$date":"2023-05-11T09:30:26.972+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4915701, "ctx":"main","msg":"Initialized wire specification","attr":{"spec":{"incomingExternalClient":{"minWireVersion":0,"maxWireVersion":17},"incomingInternalClient":{"minWireVersion":0,"maxWireVersion":17},"outgoing":{"minWireVersion":6,"maxWireVersion":17},"isInternalClient":true}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-05-11T09:30:26.973+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23285,   "ctx":"main","msg":"Automatically disabling TLS 1.0, to force-enable TLS 1.0 specify --sslDisabledProtocols 'none'"}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-05-11T09:30:26.975+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4648601, "ctx":"main","msg":"Implicit TCP FastOpen unavailable. If TCP FastOpen is required, set tcpFastOpenServer, tcpFastOpenClient, and tcpFastOpenQueueSize."}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-05-11T09:30:26.977+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":5123008, "ctx":"main","msg":"Successfully registered PrimaryOnlyService","attr":{"service":"TenantMigrationDonorService","namespace":"config.tenantMigrationDonors"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-05-11T09:30:26.977+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":5123008, "ctx":"main","msg":"Successfully registered PrimaryOnlyService","attr":{"service":"TenantMigrationRecipientService","namespace":"config.tenantMigrationRecipients"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-05-11T09:30:26.977+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":5123008, "ctx":"main","msg":"Successfully registered PrimaryOnlyService","attr":{"service":"ShardSplitDonorService","namespace":"config.tenantSplitDonors"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-05-11T09:30:26.977+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":5945603, "ctx":"main","msg":"Multi threading initialized"}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-05-11T09:30:26.977+00:00"},"s":"F",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":6384300, "ctx":"main","msg":"Writing fatal message","attr":{"message":"terminate() called. An exception is active; attempting to gather more information\n"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-05-11T09:30:26.977+00:00"},"s":"F",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":6384300, "ctx":"main","msg":"Writing fatal message","attr":{"message":"std::exception::what(): Operation not permitted\nActual exception type: std::system_error\n\n"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-05-11T09:30:27.049+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":31380,   "ctx":"main","msg":"BACKTRACE","attr":{"bt":{"backtrace":[{"a":"560B05D0C6A4","b":"560B00EFA000","o":"4E126A4","s":"_ZN5mongo18stack_trace_detail12_GLOBAL__N_119printStackTraceImplERKNS1_7OptionsEPNS_14StackTraceSinkE.constprop.362","C":"mongo::stack_trace_detail::(anonymous namespace)::printStackTraceImpl(mongo::stack_trace_detail::(anonymous namespace)::Options const&, mongo::StackTraceSink*) [clone .constprop.362]","s+":"1F4"},{"a":"560B05D0EBE9","b":"560B00EFA000","o":"4E14BE9","s":"_ZN5mongo15printStackTraceEv","C":"mongo::printStackTrace()","s+":"29"},{"a":"560B05D08F37","b":"560B00EFA000","o":"4E0EF37","s":"_ZN5mongo12_GLOBAL__N_111myTerminateEv","C":"mongo::(anonymous namespace)::myTerminate()","s+":"D7"},{"a":"560B05E939C6","b":"560B00EFA000","o":"4F999C6","s":"_ZN10__cxxabiv111__terminateEPFvvE","C":"__cxxabiv1::__terminate(void (*)())","s+":"6"},{"a":"560B05E93A01","b":"560B00EFA000","o":"4F99A01","s":"_ZSt9terminatev","C":"std::terminate()","s+":"11"},{"a":"560B05E93B3B","b":"560B00EFA000","o":"4F99B3B","s":"__cxa_throw","s+":"4B"},{"a":"560B02E0F737","b":"560B00EFA000","o":"1F15737","s":"_ZSt20__throw_system_errori.cold.24","C":"std::__throw_system_error(int) [clone .cold.24]","s+":"2F"},{"a":"560B05EAFD39","b":"560B00EFA000","o":"4FB5D39","s":"_ZNSt6thread15_M_start_threadESt10unique_ptrINS_6_StateESt14default_deleteIS1_EEPFvvE","C":"std::thread::_M_start_thread(std::unique_ptr<std::thread::_State, std::default_delete<std::thread::_State> >, void (*)())","s+":"29"},{"a":"560B03DC2D8A","b":"560B00EFA000","o":"2EC8D8A","s":"_ZN5mongo27startSignalProcessingThreadENS_13LogFileStatusE","C":"mongo::startSignalProcessingThread(mongo::LogFileStatus)","s+":"11A"},{"a":"560B0302163E","b":"560B00EFA000","o":"212763E","s":"_ZN5mongo11mongod_mainEiPPc","C":"mongo::mongod_main(int, char**)","s+":"B4E"},{"a":"560B02E1046E","b":"560B00EFA000","o":"1F1646E","s":"main","s+":"E"},{"a":"7F0F83F86D90","b":"7F0F83F5D000","o":"29D90","s":"__libc_init_first","s+":"90"},{"a":"7F0F83F86E40","b":"7F0F83F5D000","o":"29E40","s":"__libc_start_main","s+":"80"},{"a":"560B0301BF25","b":"560B00EFA000","o":"2121F25","s":"_start","s+":"25"}],"processInfo":{"mongodbVersion":"6.0.5","gitVersion":"c9a99c120371d4d4c52cbb15dac34a36ce8d3b1d","compiledModules":[],"uname":{"sysname":"Linux","release":"5.4.0-144-generic","version":"#161-Ubuntu SMP Fri Feb 3 14:49:04 UTC 2023","machine":"x86_64"},"somap":[{"b":"560B00EFA000","elfType":3,"buildId":"3C976B679319B912CD7F7AC36B539DCD7F937343"},{"b":"7F0F83F5D000","path":"/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6","elfType":3,"buildId":"69389D485A9793DBE873F0EA2C93E02EFAA9AA3D"}]}}},"tags":[]}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-05-11T09:30:27.049+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":31445,   "ctx":"main","msg":"Frame","attr":{"frame":{"a":"560B05D0C6A4","b":"560B00EFA000","o":"4E126A4","s":"_ZN5mongo18stack_trace_detail12_GLOBAL__N_119printStackTraceImplERKNS1_7OptionsEPNS_14StackTraceSinkE.constprop.362","C":"mongo::stack_trace_detail::(anonymous namespace)::printStackTraceImpl(mongo::stack_trace_detail::(anonymous namespace)::Options const&, mongo::StackTraceSink*) [clone .constprop.362]","s+":"1F4"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-05-11T09:30:27.049+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":31445,   "ctx":"main","msg":"Frame","attr":{"frame":{"a":"560B05D0EBE9","b":"560B00EFA000","o":"4E14BE9","s":"_ZN5mongo15printStackTraceEv","C":"mongo::printStackTrace()","s+":"29"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-05-11T09:30:27.049+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":31445,   "ctx":"main","msg":"Frame","attr":{"frame":{"a":"560B05D08F37","b":"560B00EFA000","o":"4E0EF37","s":"_ZN5mongo12_GLOBAL__N_111myTerminateEv","C":"mongo::(anonymous namespace)::myTerminate()","s+":"D7"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-05-11T09:30:27.049+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":31445,   "ctx":"main","msg":"Frame","attr":{"frame":{"a":"560B05E939C6","b":"560B00EFA000","o":"4F999C6","s":"_ZN10__cxxabiv111__terminateEPFvvE","C":"__cxxabiv1::__terminate(void (*)())","s+":"6"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-05-11T09:30:27.049+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":31445,   "ctx":"main","msg":"Frame","attr":{"frame":{"a":"560B05E93A01","b":"560B00EFA000","o":"4F99A01","s":"_ZSt9terminatev","C":"std::terminate()","s+":"11"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-05-11T09:30:27.049+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":31445,   "ctx":"main","msg":"Frame","attr":{"frame":{"a":"560B05E93B3B","b":"560B00EFA000","o":"4F99B3B","s":"__cxa_throw","s+":"4B"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-05-11T09:30:27.049+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":31445,   "ctx":"main","msg":"Frame","attr":{"frame":{"a":"560B02E0F737","b":"560B00EFA000","o":"1F15737","s":"_ZSt20__throw_system_errori.cold.24","C":"std::__throw_system_error(int) [clone .cold.24]","s+":"2F"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-05-11T09:30:27.049+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":31445,   "ctx":"main","msg":"Frame","attr":{"frame":{"a":"560B05EAFD39","b":"560B00EFA000","o":"4FB5D39","s":"_ZNSt6thread15_M_start_threadESt10unique_ptrINS_6_StateESt14default_deleteIS1_EEPFvvE","C":"std::thread::_M_start_thread(std::unique_ptr<std::thread::_State, std::default_delete<std::thread::_State> >, void (*)())","s+":"29"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-05-11T09:30:27.049+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":31445,   "ctx":"main","msg":"Frame","attr":{"frame":{"a":"560B03DC2D8A","b":"560B00EFA000","o":"2EC8D8A","s":"_ZN5mongo27startSignalProcessingThreadENS_13LogFileStatusE","C":"mongo::startSignalProcessingThread(mongo::LogFileStatus)","s+":"11A"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-05-11T09:30:27.049+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":31445,   "ctx":"main","msg":"Frame","attr":{"frame":{"a":"560B0302163E","b":"560B00EFA000","o":"212763E","s":"_ZN5mongo11mongod_mainEiPPc","C":"mongo::mongod_main(int, char**)","s+":"B4E"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-05-11T09:30:27.049+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":31445,   "ctx":"main","msg":"Frame","attr":{"frame":{"a":"560B02E1046E","b":"560B00EFA000","o":"1F1646E","s":"main","s+":"E"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-05-11T09:30:27.049+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":31445,   "ctx":"main","msg":"Frame","attr":{"frame":{"a":"7F0F83F86D90","b":"7F0F83F5D000","o":"29D90","s":"__libc_init_first","s+":"90"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-05-11T09:30:27.049+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":31445,   "ctx":"main","msg":"Frame","attr":{"frame":{"a":"7F0F83F86E40","b":"7F0F83F5D000","o":"29E40","s":"__libc_start_main","s+":"80"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-05-11T09:30:27.049+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":31445,   "ctx":"main","msg":"Frame","attr":{"frame":{"a":"560B0301BF25","b":"560B00EFA000","o":"2121F25","s":"_start","s+":"25"}}}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.py", line 637, in <module>
    subprocess.run(get_final_command_line_args(), check=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/subprocess.py", line 524, in run
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, process.args,
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['mongod', '--bind_ip_all']' died with <Signals.SIGABRT: 6>.
alok@alok-HP-Laptop-14s-cf3xxx:/tmp$ docker -v
Docker version 20.10.5, build 55c4c88
```

What can be the reason of

```
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['mongod', '--bind_ip_all']' died with <Signals.SIGABRT: 6>
```

What I am missing so its not able to run?

Comment: I'm guessing this could be a `docker` issue.  How did you install `docker`?  Do other containers function normally?

Comment: I install docker using `sudo apt install` and other containers are wokring nicely.

Comment: The log indicates this is some sort of permissions error: `Operation not permitted\nActual exception type: std::system_error`.  The stack trace shows the call immediately prior to the throw was `std::thread::_M_start_thread(std::unique_ptr<std::thread::_State, std::default_delete<std::thread::_State> >, void (*)())`.  Hope that helps narrow things down.

Answer (score -1):

Upgrading `Docker version 20.10.5, build 55c4c88` to latest version fix this problem.